# Shortening Rails Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

How might I be able to shorten these extremely lengthy routes in my rails application?

```
# routes.rb

  resources :courses do
    resources :sections do
      resources :lessons do
        resources :sub_lessons
      end  
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to follow the rails [oficial guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting). It is considered a good practice to avoid nesting resources more than 1 level deep. That said, if you really need this level of nesting you can use the `shallow` option. this way at least your routes will be cleaner. As noted in the documentation cited above:

> One way to avoid deep nesting (as recommended above) is to generate the collection actions scoped under the parent, so as to get a sense of the hierarchy, but to not nest the member actions. In other words, to only build routes with the minimal amount of information to uniquely identify the resource

You could try something like this:

```
resources :courses, shallow: true do
  resources :sections, shallow: true do
    resources :lessons, shallow: true do
      resources :sub_lessons
    end  
  end
end
```

Just play around with this a little and use `rake routes` to see how your routes are looking like.

However, what you should ask yourself is, for example do I need to have lessons routed under sections? May be its better to split them, something like:

```
resources :courses do
  resources :sections
end

resources :lessons do
  resources :sub_lessons
end
```

It all depends on the scope you need in what action, for example if at certain action you need to limit lessons based on courses but not in sections, then you will only need the course id passed as a parameter.